# Make php array case in-sensitive

Tags: php, arrays, case-insensitive

if someone searches "TestING" it should still read as "testing".   I have a php file included into my webpages search to block certain terms. but i have to add each case in for every word. is there a quick fix so the case does not matter?

```
<?

$blocked=array('nude','nsfw','xrated');

?>
```

Comment: How are you using `$blocked`? There are several ways to do this, but it will depend on what functions you're using.

Comment: The array contains what it contains - what you should be asking how to compare it to some string in a case-insensitive manner

Comment: Always have a look in the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using strstr, you can replace it with [stristr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php), which is the case insensitive version

```
if(stristr($_GET[q],$term)==false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing things instead of always checking with `strtolower` is instead of `in_array`, use this function.

```
function in_arrayi($needle, $haystack) {
    return in_array(strtolower($needle), array_map('strtolower', $haystack));
}
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#89256

Answer (score 0):

You can make everyting lowercase using [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php).

```
$var1 = "Hello";
$var2 = "hello";
if (strtolower($var1) == strtolower($var2)) {
    echo '$var1 is equal to $var2 in a case-insensitive string comparison';
}
```

Or you can use strcasecmp.

```
$var1 = "Hello";
$var2 = "hello";
if (strcasecmp($var1, $var2) == 0) {
    echo '$var1 is equal to $var2 in a case-insensitive string comparison';
}
```

Comment: how can i accomplish that